# getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined while fetching photos using a search term in my react gallery app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import apiKey from './config';

import Header from './Header';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';

class App extends Component{

    state={
        searchTerm: '',
        beachPhotos: [],
        mountainPhotos: [],
        lakePhotos: [],
        searchPhotos: [],
    };

    key= apiKey;

    componentDidMount= () =>{
        this.fetchPhotos('beach', 'beachPhotos');
        this.fetchPhotos('mountains', 'mountainPhotos');
        this.fetchPhotos('lake', 'lakePhotos');
        this.handleSearch(this.state.searchTerm);
    }

    fetchPhotos= (tag, photos) =>{
        fetch(`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${this.key}&tags=${tag}&per_page=2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({[photos]: result.photos.photo}));
    }

    handleSearch= (query) =>{
        const {searchTerm} = this.state;

        this.setState({
        searchTerm: query,

        });

        if(query){
            this.fetchPhotos(searchTerm, 'searchPhotos');
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(<Header search={this.handleSearch}/>);
    }
}
export default App;
```

I am getting an error in the handle search callback function when I am trying to fetch photos using `this.fetchPhotos(searchTerm, 'searchPhotos')`

It throws an **error**

```
unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined {
      35 |  fetch(`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${this.key}&tags=${tag}&per_page=2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
      36 |  .then(response => response.json())
    > 37 |  .then(result => this.setState({[photos]: result.photos.photo}));
         | ^  38 |  
      39 |
}
```

here is my **Header.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';
import Navigation from './Navigation';

class Header extends Component {
    render() { 
        return(<header><h1>React Photo Gallery</h1><SearchForm search={this.props.search} /></header>);
    }
}
export default Header;
```

and here is my **SearchForm.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchForm extends Component{

    state={query: ''}

    onChange(event){
        this.setState({query: event.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.search(this.state.query);
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} >
                <input 
                    type="search" 
                    placeholder="Search"
                    name="search" 
                    required
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                    ref={ (input) => this.query = input }
                />
                <button type="submit" className="search-button">
                    <svg fill="#fff" height="24" viewBox="0 0 23 23" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </form>
         );
    }
}
export default SearchForm;
```

I hope somebody could resolve this. I am a beginner at **react.js** and spent two days looking for a solution to this but it was futile. I would really appreciate any help.